# Google app engine+StampBarcode+pdf417 Api

Tags: java, google-app-engine, barcode, pdf417

I want to deploy my servlet to GAE but getting following error

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Problem accessing /barcodes. Reason:

```
java.awt.Rectangle is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
```

Caused by:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.Rectangle is a restricted class. Please see the Google  App Engine developer's guide for more details.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.reject(Runtime.java:50)
    at com.barcodelib.barcode.a.b.a.(a.java)
    at com.barcodelib.barcode.a.b.c.(c.java)
    at com.barcodelib.barcode.a.i.(i.java)
    at com.barcodelib.barcode.PDF417.a(PDF417.java)
    at com.barcodelib.barcode.AbstractBarcode.renderBarcode(AbstractBarcode.java)
    at PDF417Barcodes.doGet(PDF417Barcodes.java:49)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)

```
servlet
 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException 
        { 
            try { 
                PDF417 barcode = new PDF417(); 
                barcode.setData("PDF417"); 

                ServletOutputStream servletoutputstream = response.getOutputStream(); 

                response.setContentType("image/jpeg"); 
                response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 
                response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
                response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); 

                // Generate PDF-417 barcode & output to ServletOutputStream
                barcode.renderBarcode(servletoutputstream); 

            } catch (Exception e) { 
                throw new ServletException(e); 
            } 
        }
```

It working fine with tomcat but not working with GAE, Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your barcode library uses `java.awt.Rectangle`, and as the error message states, it's a restricted class. This restriction applies to GAE only, it's not a general restriction which is why it works in Tomcat.

This page https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/jrewhitelist lists all the *allowed* JRE classes, so if you're using directly or indirectly a class not listed there it will fail.

You can either not use GAE, or try to find a library that advertises to be GAE "safe" (disclaimer: I do not know if such a library exists).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if you aware of any pdf417 barcode api which works with GAE ?

Comment: What did my disclaimer say?

Answer (score 1):

GAE does not support all classes from standard JDK. Please see the following link

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/jrewhitelist

here you will find a list of allowed classes. It seems to be that your pdf417 barcodelib library is using a not allowed class. So your app will run on a standard and standalone tomcat but not on GAE.